# Проблема списка внутри словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

```
dict0 = {}
mark = [1, 22, 34]
dict0[0] = mark
print(dict0)
mark[2] = 'SOS'
dict0[1] = mark
print(dict0)
```

Вывод таков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать так чтобы при изменении значений списка mark не менялся 0-ый элемент словаря?

Comment: Не присваивать обоим элементам один и тот же список.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict0 = {}
mark = [1, 22, 34]
dict0[0] = mark.copy()
print(dict0)
mark[2] = 'SOS'
dict0[1] = mark
print(dict0)
```

вывод:

```
{0: [1, 22, 34]}
{0: [1, 22, 34], 1: [1, 22, 'SOS']}
```

Comment: спс, там еще можно срезы применить